# Which game engine does "Ridiculous Fishing"(iOS) use?

Tags: ios

Does it use game engine or just c++ libs? Its UI is concise and smooth.

Comment: See the [FAQ] about "what technology some particular game used". Voting to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was made with [openFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) and a custom library for spritesheet rendering, as told by Zach Gage (one of the developers) in the [Ridiculous Fishing Reddit IAmA](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1ah6mg/were_the_creators_of_ridiculous_fishing_ask_us/c8xd4cf):

> I think the biggest tool I have is a very tiny library I wrote about 2
>   years ago with some help from my friend Ramsey Nasser. It's opensource
>   here: https://github.com/stfj/ofxSpriteSheetRenderer although the docs
>   aren't great.
>
> I use OpenFrameworks for all of the ease of getting setup in xcode and
>   some of the event structure, but all of my openGL calls go through
>   that custom library. It handles spritesheets (and on the fly created
>   sprite sheets), rotation, batching, layers, antialiased shape and line
>   drawing, etc. It's how we managed to have RF run so well even on super
>   old devices